# How can I translate my final research title?

Tags: noun-phrases

I'm trying to translate my final research title for degree validation.

Which one would be correct?

> - Body Image Perception Among Adults Who Practice Body Building in **Lavras City** - MG
> - Body Image Perception Among Adults Who Practice Body Building in **the city of Lavras** - MG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report titles should be succinct and precise. ["Bodybuilding" is much more widely used than "body building"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=body+building%2Cbodybuilding&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbody%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbodybuilding%3B%2Cc0) and is one word shorter. "Who practice" can be shortened to "practicing" without loss of clarity. Not everyone knows what or where Lavras is. So: **"Body image perception among adults practicing bodybuilding in Lavras[, MG], Brazil"**.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, how do you refer to Lavras in Brazil in English?

It's just Lavras. Lavras City implies it's often referred to as Lavras City, which as far as I know, it's not. So "... in the City of Lavras - MG" seems more correct, though I might look at other dissertation title styles in your discipline, to compare what's the typical style used when mentioning the location of a study.